# Proc Freq Save Output One-Way Results

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with Yes / No values.

I've figured out that I can use Proc Freq to generate a table of "One-Way" results which displays the proportion per row i.e. 60% yes, 40% no. However, this is shown in a pop-up window by default.

I want to save these results to a dataset for potential manipulation but I can't figure it out. Searching online it says I need to enter additional commands in the table and output statement for this to work. This is my sample (incorrect) code:

```
proc freq data = results noprint;
tables check / pct_row;
output out = table1;
run;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close, the `OUT` goes after the `/` on the TABLES statement.

```
proc freq data = results noprint;
tables check / out=table1 pct_row outpct;
run;
```

Comment: That worked with a few changes. Had to take away pct_row (was not a valid command).

outpct did not work - "no valid for a one-way table"

So basically just tables check / out = table1; Thanks!